# How to remove lighting and keep objects visible

Tags: shaders, light, color

I am trying to film / animate a short film utilizing Invidia's GAN AI to generate the various backgrounds for a surreal effect. Before I attempt filming I need some help using blender.

In order to generate these backgrounds, different textures are applied/generated in accordance to a certain colour value (see [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXFmZsv0Ddw) and [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8kw8g1_JdY)). Is there a way for me to completely remove lighting in Blender while still having objects remain visible and still retain their colour?

In other words, how do I make sure that the colour I texture objects are unchanged by that of the lighting and compression other any renders. Is it possible to recreate some of the techniques shown in the video below in Blender?

I am extremely inexperienced with the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the rendering engine to “workbench” and set the shading as flat. Although if you have textures and material you may can’t use that.

If so, try switching to EEVEE/Cycles. Set the color (I’m not sure what it’s called, but maybe a color correction?) to “Standard” instead of “filmic “. It’s located on the color management, properties tab. Then, delete all shader and replace it with an image texture/color (just the emission). Without a shader, the final result should be flat without shading. You can also mess with the world setting for better result.

(If you’re confused about the emission, it’s using *only* image/color, like ColorRamp, image texture, noise texture, other textures, and yeah stuff like that. I believe it would work)

Oh, and I remember NVDIA GauGan is using a color mapping (if it’s what it called.) There shouldn’t be any texture on the material, isn’t it?